# Objective-C method signatures are the same after Swift conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I've got two methods in my objective-c library that, after conversion to Swift, seem to have the same method signature.  They are as follows in Objective-C:

```
- (void)doSomething:(UIViewController *)viewController __attribute__((deprecated));
- (BOOL)doSomething:(UIViewController *)viewController error:(NSError **)error;
```

From what I've read about Swift conversion of methods using NSErrors + BOOL return values in Objective-C, these methods will end up having the following Swift Method Signatures:

```
func doSomething(viewController: UIViewController)
func doSomething(viewController: UIViewController) throws
```

Since the first call is actually deprecated in Objective-C, is there a way to force calls made to to this method to use the second signature (ensuring that I can take advantage of the thrown errors)?

I'm trying to call the method in the following way:

```
do {
    try myObjectInstance.doSomething(self)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

This approach seems to default to the first declaration, which is giving me a warning that a) the method is deprecated and b) there is nothing to catch because no errors are thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE` macro to mark it unavailable to Swift:

```
- (void)doSomething:(UIViewController *)viewController
   __attribute__((deprecated)) NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE("use the throwing variant");
```

Then the Swift compiler will choose the only available method, which is the other one.

(In my tests this seems to break autocomplete — you may want to [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com) about that.)

Comment: Oh, a library update would be unfortunate if that's the only way that this can be done.  That said, better one solution than none! Thanks!!

Comment: Presumably, you could also make a separate Obj-C method (in a category or something) which is included in the Swift target just to help with the interop, and calls the appropriate one.